# Twitter Users on here?

Tags: social-network, career, networking, education

I know there have been some twitter threads on here so I have to make this a question as I didn't want this to be buried at the end of a ton of posts since this is more of a group networking invite.

About a year and a half ago I started a "Twibe" for sound designers.

What a Twibe does is it aggregates tweets from the members into the Twibe feed using specific keywords without having to follow that twitter user. Say for example someone has occasional interesting tweets about Sound Design, but happens to not be able to separate business and private and list a bunch of disgusting food that they're eating all the time or maybe complaining about their love life or whatever. This way, you only see the tweets from them that feature these set key words.

I have the keywords for the group set to Sound Design, SoundDesigners and Audio. So if you use any of those in your tweet, it will be fed to the Twibe.

We have some great and legendary members on board including Practitioners, Educators, Students, Companies, Tutorial Creators, Other networks and more. We try to help each other out with networking, promotion and learning opportunities by re-tweeting each others posts, contributing new posts to the Twibe and it's dead simple to use. I've met some great new colleagues through there over time and I've learned a lot from others.

Would you like to come join us? (my obligatory question to satisfy this post, lol)

http://www.twibes.com/group/SoundDesigners or the master shortened URL is http://twib.es/3DM

There's a big green arrow button that says "Tweet to Join". It uses your Twitter profile info as your Twibe profile info. You just have to allow Twibes to access your twitter account.

Also, in order to not to have to visit the twibe and see the aggregate feed be sure to follow these instructions:

Be sure to click “Make Twitter List” just above the members’ photos on the twibe page, Twibes will create a Twitter list for you that you will be able to see on Twitter. Twibes will add/remove people from the Twitter list as they join or leave the twibe, usually within a day or two.

It's as simple as that.

I'm on there and Twitter as @SynSynth and I look forward to seeing you all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joined up! See everyone around on the Twibe!

@everyone

Twibe is what seems to be a separate entity connected to twitter. Go to the link Synth posted and click tweet to join twibe. Itll take you to your twitter page and paste it automatically into your tweet bar. Tweet it, and it will say you need to allow twibe access to your account. Say yes or ok and itll redirect you to the twibe site. Verify with your email address, and go check it to click the link in your email to verify. Once done, youre golden.

Answer (score 0):

may be a silly question, but how do I follow the twibe?

Comment: @ragamesound there's a big green arrow buttom that says "Tweet to Join". It uses your Twitter profile info as your Twibe profile info. You just have to allow Twibes to access your twitter account. Simple as that.