# Perhaps SSD needs a chat space??

Tags: ssd

Don't get me wrong... I think the question format of this site is great, but sometimes I discover things ([like this](http://vimeo.com/34405214)) which I'd like to share in a more conversational way. Also, how many comments have you seen loosely wrapped up as questions just to comply with the rules of the site?

Perhaps there's another space online where you are all doing this already, if so I'd love to know where, otherwise let's discuss the idea.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this is something that will more than likely be happening in the next few months... Just a heads up ;-)

Comment: I still want those t-shirts and merchandising. :)

Comment: Well how about that... Curious about how it's going to integrate with the rest of the site - reputation etc. 

Comment: @Mark, the reputation and all that will stay as is :-) 
@Utopia, maybe you can do that? hehe, I'd like a desk lamp with an SSD shadow (batman style) for my desk... 

Answer (score 3):

If SSD had a chat space I'd spend my entire workday there and not get any work done...

Comment: Apparently one of you out there can't take a joke :/

Comment: Well the rest of us can ;-)

Comment: Who made a joke?

Comment: @Christian @Steve aww :)

Answer (score 1):

SSD chat is a great idea +1!!!

Answer (score 0):

could probably just do it by adding a twitter feed that updates anytime someone tweets @ssd

Comment: Or perhaps hashtags #ssd? But @Rene makes a good point, a fair amount of us are on twitter. I gave in and joined expressly because of it. Here's the ongoing list of usernames: http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/2941/hey-guys-girls-so-who-tweets-here

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use the Twibe thing @Syndicate Synthetique made in this [post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/6196/twitter-users-on-here)